# How to validate file to be uploaded?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, liferay, portlet

I am working on liferay project. I have to put file upload functionality. For which I have used

```
<bridge:inputFile/>
```

But my upload method is not called when I try to upload a blank file of 0 bytes. Actually my validation for blank file is inside my upload method.